# Get my selected data from a list ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I have a list of items,I need to get the selected data once i click on it 
Here is my list:

```
<ion-content class="outer-content" no-border-top>
    <ion-list lines (click)="openSubCat($event,category)">
      <ion-list-header>
        Shop For
      </ion-list-header>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="man" item-left></ion-icon>
         Men
        <ion-icon item-right ></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
       <ion-item menuClose>
       <ion-icon name="woman" item-left></ion-icon>
         Women
        <ion-icon  item-right></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-icon name="baby" item-left></ion-icon>
          Kids
        <ion-icon  item-right></ion-icon>
      </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
</ion-content>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hashbang` in a similar way to how you would use `${''}` for id in jquery.

```
 <ion-item #menItem (click)="itemClicked(menuItem)>
  ....
 </ion-item>
```

Then in your `console.log` will give you the properties of the `ion-item`. That can work well for `inputs` but not so much structural tags.

```
itemClicked(item){
   console.log(item);
}
```

I think there is a better way to go about what you are trying to achieve though. It might be better to create your list in the code as an object literal and then pass to the view to use in a `*ngFor` . This makes your code compact yet complex and your view concise and neat.

So in your page component

```
categoryArray: Array<any> = [];
....
ionViewDidEnter(){
   this.categoryArray = [{
      value:'Men',
      icon: 'man',
      view:'viewToGoTo'
   },{
      value:'Woman',
      icon: 'woman',
      view:'viewToGoTo'
   },{
      value:'Kids',
      icon: 'baby',
      view:'viewToGoTo'
   }];
}
```

Then in the view you can write a neat `*ngFor`

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of categoryArray; let idx=index (click)="openSubCat(item)">
    <ion-icon [name]="item.icon" item-left></ion-icon>
      {{ item.value }}
    <ion-icon item-right ></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

your click event will then pass

```
Object {value: "Men", icon: "man", view: "viewToGoTo"}
```

That way in the click event you get a neat package of the properties that you require to be passed, and can be easily updated and edited. Or you can target a specific value with and idx, which makes it more versatile if complexity is added to the project. As well as adding the coolness in `*ngFor` like pipes and filters

```
 (click)="openSubCat(item.view,idx)"
```

You could then also make the `categoryArray` into an interface that can then be used throughout your code base.